# Can't import SVG into React Component (says module not found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

**Before marking this question as a duplicate, please note that I have already viewed the following and their soutions, but to no avail:**
[Cannot import SVG file into react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874514/cannot-import-svg-file-into-react)
[React SVG import as a Component does not render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176521/react-svg-import-as-a-component-does-not-render)
[React/Typescript cannot import svg file as component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69366545/react-typescript-cannot-import-svg-file-as-component)

I'm trying to import an SVG into my ReactJs 18 component, but during "build" it says it can't find the module (typescript detects it just fine with the file open though).

```
import wordmark from '../Images/wordmark.svg';
.
.
.
export const Header: FunctionComponent<{}> = () => {
  const { banner } = useContext(BannerContext);
  const { deviceMetadata } = useShadowController();

  // Just render plain old header
  if (!deviceMetadata) {
    return (
      <section className="site-header">
        <div className="site-header-logo">
          <Link to={routes.home}>
            <img
              height="25px"
              src={wordmark}
              alt="test"
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
.
.
.
}
```

The svg has the following (had to edit some parts to hide personal info):

```
<svg width="134" height="18" viewBox="0 0 134 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<rect width="134" height="18" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(0 -0.0104762) scale(0.00142857 0.0106349)"/>
</pattern>
<image id="image0" width="700" height="96" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,confidential"/>
</defs>
</svg>
```

**I have tried the following:**

- Creating a index.d.ts file with the following:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React = require("react");
  export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

- Importing the svg has a component (import { Component as logo } from .....)
- Importing the svg has default (import { default as logo } from ....)
- Placing the svg in the same directory as the component
- Updating tsconfig.json
- Passing the relative path directly into src (doesn't throw any errors but also doesn't render)

At this point I'm at my wits end. Any help is much appreciated.